# Combining errors of measurements where one is a quantity the other is a percentage

Tags: measurements, error-analysis

I'm still very new to physics and i am a bit stuck on this one as its the first time i've seen error margins with % rather than actual quantities.

Say i have two measurements with margins of errors:

```
a +/- 2 meters
b +/- 20%
```

Now you want to multiply a and b together to get `ab`, what would the error margin become in this case ? Do you give it in units or % ? To how many significant figures ??

Can you still use the square root of the sum of the squares in this case? Or is there a different approach entirely here?

Do you normally convert 20% to an actual value of b then apply the square root of the sum of the squares of a and b ?

Comment: Yes the usual approach applies : sqrt of sum of squares of fractional errors. So if a=10m and b=200% then error in ab is sqrt(0.2^2+0.1^2).

Comment: So you don't need to convert 20% to (b*0.2)^2 in the sqrt of the sum of the squares?

Comment: No. Treat the % just the same as if it were a quantity with units. NB: in my comment above the sqrt gives the fractional error in ab not the absolute error.

Comment: Oh we treat them the same, that seems odd to treat them the same since 2 meters is precise, and 20% is variable depending on value of b.

Comment: Ok I misunderstood. If say b=200m +/- 20% then fractional error is 0.2 which does not depend on value of b. Whereas if a=10m +/- 2m then fractional error is also 0.2 but this does depend on value of a since if a=20m then fractional error is 0.1.

Comment: So i should convert `a +/- 2 meters` to a a fractional error first?

Comment: Yes. Everything should be converted to fractional errors first before putting them into the formula. The answer will also be a fractional error.